# Python loop not taking any inputs

Tags: arrays, loops, python-3.9

Whats wrong with this code? I fail to see the error. The compiler shows this output.(N.B: I'm new to python)

output:Enter element no: 1
None

```
no_of_zeros = 0
for i in range(0, 5):
    array[i] = input(print("Enter element no:", i+1))
    if(array[i]==0):
        array[i] = 1
        is_zero += 1

sum = 0
for j in range(0, 5):
    sum = sum + array[j]

print(sum)
print(no_of_zeros)
```

Comment: Where do you declare the variable "array"?

Comment: I heard python does not need declaration @La-comadreja

Comment: Except you don't know whether it's a tuple or a list, for example. You need to specify.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access an index that doesn't exist.  Pre-allocate `array` or use array.append.

```
array = list(range(0,5))
no_of_zeros = 0
for i in range(0, 5):
    array[i] = int(input("Enter element no{}:".format(i+1)))
    if(array[i]==0):
        array[i] = 1
        is_zero += 1

sum = 0
for j in range(0, 5):
    sum = sum + array[j]

print(sum)
print(no_of_zeros)
```

Also that is a very C-ish way of doing things (which is fine).  Python can make that code much simpler.  Once you catch on to the Python way of doing things you will see why Python is so popular.  Learn list comprehension for instance.

Your code can be reduced to three lines ...

```
array = [ int(input("Enter element no{}:".format(i+1))) for i in range(5) ]
print(sum(array))
print(sum([ 1 for x in array if x==0 ]))
```